# Entity Framework: admin site generator

Tags: entity-framework

Is there any tool to generate CRUD admin site from Entity Framework Model?
Something like [PLINQO](http://plinqo.com/) has built in.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need an [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/(S(y3u2uc45kakrr555dijiwvf2))/DynamicData/) website. The latest version supports Entity Framework if I'm not mistaking.